# Syntax error when creating trigger from PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, triggers, syntax-error

I'd like to create a trigger from the following `PHP` code.

```
  $sql = 'delimiter $$';
  $pdo->exec($sql);
  $sql = 'create trigger avoid_empty_employee_insert before insert on `employee`
          for each row begin
            if name = "" then set name = null; end if;
          end$$';
  $pdo->exec($sql);
  $sql = 'delimiter ;';
  $pdo->exec($sql);
```

When I run the the code in `MySQL` it works and the trigger is created.

PHP shows the following error.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
>   violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'delimiter $$' at line 1

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Definitely do not try to change the delimiter when you're executing the statement via the API. `DELIMITER` is a [mysql client built-in command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-commands.html), it is not recognized by the MySQL server-side parser.

You don't need it anyway. The purpose of `DELIMITER` is to remove the ambiguity of semicolons that may appear within the body of a trigger or stored routine. Since the API is for executing one statement at a time, there's no ambiguity. The SQL parser just treats the whole string as one statement anyway.

Likewise, do not end the create trigger statement with `$$`. You don't need any statement terminator, but the SQL parser accepts `;` as an optional statement terminator because so many people put it there even though they don't have to.

The next problem is that you when you use column names in a trigger, you have to prefix them with either `NEW.` or `OLD.` -- in an insert trigger, you can only use `NEW.` If you don't prefix the column, MySQL assumes you meant to set a system variable like `tmpdir` or `slow_query_log`.

If you are still getting the 1193 error, I suggest that you didn't change *both* references to the `name` column to `NEW.name`.

I tested the following using PHP 5.4.24 and MySQL 5.6.20, and it worked:

```
$sql = "create trigger avoid_empty_employee_insert before insert on `employee`
      for each row begin
          if NEW.name = '' then set NEW.name = null; end if;
      end";
$pdo->exec($sql);
```

You don't need to delimit the column name of `name`, because it is not a MySQL reserved word. [The set of reserved words is documented.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html)

Answer (score 0):

try that :

```
  $sql = 'create trigger avoid_empty_employee_insert before insert on `employee`
      for each row begin
        if name = "" then set name = null; end if; END;';
  $pdo->exec($sql);
```

Comment: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1193 Unknown system variable 'name' `

Comment: have you name in your employee table ?

Comment: yes "name varchar(255) not null" ... btw. the code works in MySQL.

Comment: yes , you tagged mysql , have you other then mysql ?

Comment: What do you mean by "have you other than mysql?"

Comment: i mean if you using something else then mysql ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating the trigger using code, you might not need to set/reset the `DELIMITER`. Changing the DELIMITER is important for CLIs.

Just ignore those lines in your php code that changes them.

Your code becomes only:

```
$sql = 'create trigger `avoid_empty_employee_insert` before insert
        on `employee`
        for each row
        begin
            if `name` = "" then set `name` = null; end if;
        end';
$pdo->exec($sql);
```

Comment: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1193 Unknown system variable 'name' `

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating the trigger using code, you might not need to set/reset the `DELIMITER`.

Just ignore those lines in your php code that changes them.

Your code becomes only:

```
$sql = 'create trigger avoid_empty_employee_insert before insert on `employee`
          for each row begin
            if NEW.`name` = "" then set NEW.`name` = null; end if;
          end$$';
$pdo->exec($sql);
```

Comment: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1193 Unknown system variable 'name' `

Comment: What have you changed?

Comment: The `name` is escaped.

Comment: can you please paste the structure of your employee table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61177/discussion-between-peter-and-xralf).

Comment: `NAME` is not a MySQL reserved word. [Check the list.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: Thanks @Bill. Better to be safe anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Mayby this helps:

```
$sql = "delimiter //\n";
$pdo->exec($sql);
$sql = "create trigger avoid_empty_employee_insert before insert on employee\n
      for each row\n 
        begin\n
        if new.name = '' then\n 
        set new.name = null;\n
        end if;\n
      end//\n";
$pdo->exec($sql);
$sql = 'delimiter ;';
$pdo->exec($sql);
```